# boost::serialization of boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I've moved one of my member variables from a std::map to a boost::unordered_map for the performance benefits on insertion. However, this has broken my use of boost serialization for export/importing from an archive.

I've tried looking but can't find it anyway, I was wondering if there was a header I could include that would provide serialization to this class?

Many thanks.

Comment: see if this link is helpful http://groups.google.com/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/79c23f608ab0beee?fwc=2

Comment: seriously, how can boost dont have native support for serializing theyr own goddam containers?

Comment: @Icebone1000 different libraries, written by different people...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [unordered_map_serialization.h](https://github.com/dlidstrom/ntest/blob/master/unordered_map_serialization.h) in my distributed opening book learning project. It should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Is this still necessary in the latest release (eg, 1.48+)?

Comment: It seems this functionality was included with Boost as of 1.47: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5265.

Comment: This works! Thanks Daniel! I didn't find this functionality in boost 1.54.

Answer (score 2):

I saw someone replaced map with unordered_map in serialization/map.hpp and this worked