# Couldn't load data back after serializing onto disk using boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I was able to save my data onto disk using boost serialization.  However, I was unable to retrieve back the data.  Would you please show me what did I do wrong?

Thank you,

Below are my codes

```
void nDB::save_macros(string filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    //assert(ofs.good());
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << this;
}

void nDB::load_macros(string filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
    //assert(ifs.good());
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
    nDB *db = new nDB;
    ia >> db;
    *this = *db;
}
```

Below is my serialization instantiation

```
template<class Archive>
void nDB::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
    boost::unordered_map<string,macro*,myhash,cmp_str>::iterator M_IT;
    boost::unordered_map<string,layer*,myhash,cmp_str>::iterator L_IT;
    for (L_IT = _LAYERS.begin();L_IT != _LAYERS.end();L_IT++) {
        string tmpstr = L_IT->first;
        //ar & L_IT->first;
        ar & tmpstr;
        ar & *(L_IT->second);
    }
    for (M_IT = _MACROS.begin();M_IT != _MACROS.end();M_IT++) {
       string tmpstr = M_IT->first;
       //ar & M_IT->first;
       ar & tmpstr;
       ar & *(M_IT->second);
    }
}
```

Below are my run result saving run:

> Insert macro mac1 into database OK!
>   Insert macro mac2 into database OK!
>   Insert macro mac3 into database OK!
>   Insert port P1 OK!
>   Insert port P2 OK!
>   Insert port P2 OK!
>   Insert port P3 OK!
>   Insert port P1 OK!
>   Insert port P3 OK!
>   Layer mac3 is found
>   Macro mac3 has these port:
>   Port P3 is found
>   Port P1 is found
>   Port P3 of macro mac3 has use CLOCK and dir INOUT
>   Port P1 of macro mac3 has use POWER and dir OUTPUT

Below is my result loading run

> ERROR::  Could not find macro mac3 in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing too much in your `nDB::serialize` method.

Boost Serialize will happily serialize your maps for you, if you just provide `serialize` methods for your `macro` and `layer` classes.  Once you've written those, you should be able to simplify the given method to something like this:

```
template<class Archive>
void nDB::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
  ar & _LAYERS;
  ar & _MACROS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aldo, I actually have the unordered_map serialize function initizalized.  I didn't know that you can use it like that.  Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287299/boostserialization-of-boostunordered-map

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at it in detail, but I notice that you open the input and output streams differently...

In `save_macros`:

```
std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

In `load_macros`:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
```

Could that be the problem?

Comment: Hi Aldo, I've tried what you suggested but it doesn't solve it.  I've also tried saving and loading the reference instead of the pointer.  It doesn't solve it either.  So I guess I must have done something wrong systematically.